# Validate year range using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

These are the valid years in header of our source file, in copyright line:

```
2016
2007,2016
2007-2010,2016
2010,2012-2016
```

current year (2016) should be part of it.

invalid:

```
2016,2007 # not in order
2010-2007,2016 #range not in order.
2010-2015 # current year missing.
```

I made script as below, still working on it, is there a better way to check the same?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'first';
use Time::Piece;

my $t = Time::Piece->new();
my $currentYear=$t->year;

my $filename="sample.txt"; # this file name will be passed-in to the script.
my $fileContent=`cat $filename`;
my $copyrightFound = first { /copyright .* Shakespeare/i } $fileContent;
if (!$copyrightFound) {
     print "\nERROR: Copyright missing\n";
     exit;
}
#copyright Found
print $fileContent;
if ($fileContent =~ /Copyright \(c\) (.*) by Bill Shakespeare\s+.*All rights reserved./) {
    print "\nCopyright is good: $1\n";
    my $years = $1;
    print "\n$years, $currentYear\n";
    #e.g: 2016
    if ($years !~ ', ' && $years !~ '-') {
       print "\nerror\n" if ($years !~ /$currentYear/);
    }
    #e.g: 2010-2016
    elsif ($years !~ ', ') {
       print "\nError\n" if ($years !~ /\-$currentYear$/);
    }
    #eg: 2010, 2016
    elsif ($years !~ '-') {
       print "\nError\n" if ($years !~ /\, $currentYear$/);
    }
    #e.g: 2008, 2010, 2011-2016
    elsif ($years =~ '-' && $years =~ ', ') {
       print "\nError 5\n" if ($years !~ /\d\d\d\d, \d\d\d\d\-$currentYear$/);
    }
    else {
       print "invalid format"
    }

} else {
      print "\nCopyright needs to be fixed\n";
}
```

sample.txt has:

```
Copyright (c) 2008, 2010, 2011-2016 by Bill Shakespeare
All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Set::IntSpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan) to validate the dates:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Set::IntSpan qw();

my $currentYear = 2016;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/\s+//g;
    my $ok = 0;
    if (Set::IntSpan->valid($_)) { # Checks order
        my $set = Set::IntSpan->new($_);
        my @years = $set->elements();
        $ok = 1 if grep { $_ == $currentYear } @years;
    }
    print "$ok : $_\n";
}

__DATA__
2007
2007, 2016
2007-2010,2016
2010,2012-2016
2016,2007
2010-2007,2016
2010-2015
```

This prints:

```
0 : 2007
1 : 2007,2016
1 : 2007-2010,2016
1 : 2010,2012-2016
0 : 2016,2007
0 : 2010-2007,2016
0 : 2010-2015
```

Simplifying using `member` instead of `grep`, as recommended by `pilcrow` in a comment:

```
my $ok = 0;
if (Set::IntSpan->valid($_)) { 
    my $set = Set::IntSpan->new($_);
    $ok = 1 if $set->member($currentYear);
}
print "$ok : $_\n";
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot, can you pls explain what `grep { $_ == $currentYear } @years` will do ? I didn't understand why we need `$_ == $currentYear`

Comment: @Krish that line is simply searching `@years` for `$currentYear`.  It will return either a 1 element list (true) or an empty list (false).